# How to select specific node from list and apply effect to it?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an ArrayList that holds Path objects inside, and each one of those paths has it's own EventHandler. However when i mouse over a certain path then effect .setOnMouseEntered applies to all the paths inside the ArrayList and not the certain one:

```
Path path;
Group root = new Group();
ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle (MouseEvent e) {
    if (i == 0) {
    if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
        path = new Path();
        path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        path.setStrokeWidth(10);
        root.getChildren().add(path);
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(e.getX(), e.getY()));
    }
    if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(e.getX(), e.getY()));
    }
    if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        for (Path path : paths) {
        path.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEventHandler2);
        path.setOnMouseExited(mouseEventHandler2);
        path.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEventHandler2);
        }
        paths.add(path);
    }
}
}
EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseEventHandler2 = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
    if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED) {
        path.setEffect(new DropShadow(20, Color.BLACK));
    }
    if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED) {
        path.setEffect(null);
    }
    if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
        path.relocate(me.getX(), me.getY());
    }
}
};
```

So here mouseEventHandler2 is applied to all the Paths inside ArrayList paths, not that certain one which has MOUSE_ENTERED or MOUSE_EXITED

Comment: Show the code how these paths added to the scene. You may _think_ that you are mouse overing on a certain path, but actually overing on all paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating a new `Path` every time you click and drag on the scene, it is not necessary to go over the whole list of paths to assign the event handlers. Just add them to the last new path.

Besides, there's another problem, since you're using the global variable `path` on the `mouseEventHandler2`. You should refer to the path from `e.getSource()`. Otherwise, only the last path will react to mouse events.

One last problem: if you try to drag an existing path, at the same time you are creating a new one... I guess that's the `i==0` part, which doesn't make sense to me (assuming `i` is the number of paths, I don't see why you limit to just to 1 and then use a for-loop...).

Basically, these are my modifications to your code (with the second drag event handler commented, and with no limit to path creation).

```
private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseEventHandler2 = (MouseEvent me) -> {
    Path path1 = (Path)me.getSource();
    if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED) {
        path1.setEffect(new DropShadow(20, Color.BLACK));
    }
    if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED) {
        path1.setEffect(null);
    }
        if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            path1.relocate(me.getX(), me.getY());
        }
};

private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseEventHandler = (MouseEvent e) -> {
    if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
        path = new Path();
        path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        path.setStrokeWidth(10);
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        root.getChildren().add(path);
    }
    if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(e.getX(), e.getY()));
    }
    if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        path.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEventHandler2);
        path.setOnMouseExited(mouseEventHandler2);
//        path.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEventHandler2);
    }
};
```