# How to get coordinates for the center of Path in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I've got `Path` element, which is manually drawn and saved as a `Node`. I cannot figure how to get center coordinates for this entire node, so if relocate my `Path` using `relocate()` method and later decide to put it back where it was, it does not return to it's initial position. I have tried using `getLayoutX()` and `getLayoutY()` methods, but it moves my node further up from original position.

Code i use for relocate

```
class PathEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{
//element number in paths
public int n;
public PathEventHandler(int n){
    this.n=n;
}
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
    if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED) {
        paths.get(n).setEffect(new DropShadow(20, Color.BLACK));
    }
    if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED) {
        paths.get(n).setEffect(null);
    }
    if (i == 2) {
    if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
        listX.add(paths.get(n).getLayoutX());
        listY.add(paths.get(n).getLayoutY());
        paths.get(n).relocate(me.getSceneX(), me.getSceneY());
        cachePath.add(paths.get(n));
        cacheType.add("Relocate");
    }
    if (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
        if (me.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        root.getChildren().remove(paths.get(n));
        cachePath.add(paths.get(n));
        cacheType.add("Remove");
        }
    }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589503/how-to-select-specific-node-from-list-and-apply-effect-to-it), and what you've barely described in this one, I've tried to figure out what you are trying to accomplish.

Maybe it's far from there, but this short but functional code should be enough for you to understand how to deal with path creation (as for the first question) and path movement (for the actual question), all within the same mouse listener.

```
private Path path;
private double x1, y1;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

    root.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> {
        if(e.getTarget() instanceof Path){
            // Select existing path
            Path path1 = (Path)e.getTarget();

            if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET) {
                path1.setEffect(new DropShadow(20, Color.BLACK));
            } else if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET) {
                path1.setEffect(null);
            } else if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                x1=e.getX(); 
                y1=e.getY();
            } else if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                // traslate path
                path1.setTranslateX(e.getX()-x1+path1.getTranslateX());
                path1.setTranslateY(e.getY()-y1+path1.getTranslateY());
                x1=e.getX(); 
                y1=e.getY();
            } else if (e.getButton()==MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                // right-click over the path to move it to its original position
                path1.setTranslateX(0);
                path1.setTranslateY(0);
            }
        } else {
            // Generate new path
            if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                path = new Path();
                path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                path.setStrokeWidth(10);
                path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                root.getChildren().add(path);
            } else if (e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED || 
                e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {
                path.getElements().add(new LineTo(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            }
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Great! This should help me figure out how i need to store coordinates correctly or add them if i need to relocate objects. Sad thing however is that when you move objects around using your method it is a little shaky compared to `path.relocate(e.getScaleX(), e.getScaleY())` but it works as intended still!

Comment: With relocate the mouse cursor stays at the origin of the path (0,0) of its bounding bound, no where you have clicked over it. With my approach, you keep the mouse at this point. Besides, I don't see that shaky behavior you mention.